# MsProject - Updating board status based on %achieved

Tags: ms-project, kanban-board

I would like to automatically update the 'board status' column based on the % achieved. 
Is this possible?

Comment: Hi Lay, welcome! The question shows little to no effort. Have you done any research on the matter? How was that search done? What did you find out? What's blocking you from doing it? (Some ideas to improve it)

Comment: I don't have a board status column on my MsProject.  I think we may need more context to understand or answer this question. VtC until clarified, then consider re-open.